# Escaping characters/strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, escaping, html-escape-characters

How can I escape this string or shall I say characters `'"); " ' (; '") ;` to be put on this html element

```
<img src='<?=$this->webroot;?>img/document-note.png' onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this,'<?=$finalNote;?>')" />
```

The `$finalNote` variable is equal to `'"); " ' (; '") ;` this value.

I tried doing this one:

```
$finalNote = str_replace('"','\"',$finalNote);
$finalNote = str_replace("'","\'",$finalNote);
```

The output has become like this:

```
<img ;')"="" \'\")="" (;="" \'="" \"="" );="" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this,' \'\" src="/img/document-note.png">
```

My code does not make sense ( I know ^_^)

I also tried using this one:

```
$finalNote = htmlspecialchars($finalNote);
```

The output is this one:

```
<img onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this,' '&quot;); &quot; ' (; '&quot;) ;')" src="/img/document-note.png">
```

That is still wrong because when I hover the image that i have it gives me this error:
[image]

My question is that how do I escape those values properly so that I can render those on the `<img onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this,' '"); " ' (; '") ; ')" />` without those errors.

Your help will be greatly appeciated! Thanks!

Comment: shouldb't this <?=$this->webroot;?> be <?php  echo $this->webroot;?>

Comment: http://us1.php.net/addslashes

Comment: @Satya that's a shorthanded echo in php, that's just the same :)

Comment: Do you want to render these symbols into img tag right ? ); (;

Comment: @MattHarrison I also tried that one. Forgot to write it on the topic. :)

Comment: @ChinnuR Yes, I want to render those on img tags :)

Comment: Why it is tagged with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting a string into Javascript, so you first need to make sure it's valid Javascript syntax. This Javascript is then output into HTML, so you need to make sure it's proper HTML. So you're looking at two encoding steps:

```
htmlspecialchars(json_encode($string))
```

To be more exact:

```
htmlspecialchars(sprintf('tooltip.pop(this, %s)', json_encode($finalNote)))
```

This is now the properly escaped content for `onmouseover="..."`.

Comment: I'm afraid, you failed here :-P

Comment: Can you be more specific than that?

Comment: Huh, I am digging this issue since it has been posted, but you want it on a plate

Comment: @Elson Because you quoted the value which was already being quoted by `json_encode`. See new example.

Comment: @Your Very constructive, as always. :)

Comment: wow! That's super genius!
I made it to be like this  <?php $finalNote = htmlspecialchars(sprintf('tooltip.pop(this, %s)', json_encode($finalNote))); ?>
    <img src='<?=$this->webroot;?>img/document-note.png' onmouseover="<?=$finalNote;?>" />

Comment: @Your Because only my answer is super genius! ;-P

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$finalNote = " '\"); \" ' (; '\") ;";

$finalNote = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($finalNote), ENT_QUOTES);

?>

<script>

var tooltip = {
    pop: function(obj, note) {
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(note);
    }
};

</script>
<img src='img/document-note.png' onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this,'<?=$finalNote;?>');" />
```

Comment: never use htmlentities, but htmlspecialchars. the rest is okay

Comment: why did ou put slashes on the $finalNote variable? I'm guesing you're escaping them, right? how to do that with a code in it? addslashes?

Comment: htmlentities is obsoleted. It was needed then browsers didn't comprehend different encodings. But this time it just spoil and bloat your text. While you actually have to encode only few characters, which htmlspecialchars do

Comment: @ElsonSolano if you were tagging your question properly, you'd know the answer. It should have been titled "Escaping characters/strings in *javascript*"